# Iterator lose value

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code that finds the cycles in a graph. But when my recursive function returns the iterator seems to lose its value. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

vector<int > vec[100]; ///Here i hold the nodes
vector<int > ::iterator it;///Iterator for accessing "vec" elements
int viz[100],n,m;///viz remembers if a node was visited, n is the number of nodes and m the number of edges

void ham(int i)
{
    for(it=vec[i].begin();it!=vec[i].end();it++)
    {
        int j=*it; ///j is just for probing something, no real use
        if(!viz[*it])
        {
            viz[*it]=1; ///the it node is visited
            ham(*it);///I visit this node
            viz[*it]=0;///I consider this node unvisited
        }
    }
    if(i==n)///if i equals n then I print the cycle
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
            if(viz[j])
                cout<<j<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
        return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("graf.in");
    fin>>n>>m;
    for(int i=1;i<=m;i++)///reading the input and storing it in "vec"
    {
        int x,y;
        fin>>x>>y;
        vec[x].push_back(y);
        vec[y].push_back(x);
    }
    viz[1]=1;///the first node is already visited
    ham(1);///starting from the first node
    return 0;
}
```

When my function returns the iterator gain a negative value. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Is it "how do you debug code"? If so, you should tell us what platform you are using, what debugger you are using, and if you have any style preferences (logging, single stepping, post mortem, assertions or whatever).

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Also, what input are you providing to the program? And what do you mean by the "value" of an iterator?

Comment: Are you sure you want 100 vectors?  Or do you want one vector with 100 ints?  Or do you want 100 ints?

Comment: Well I'm sure that I need 100 vectors. I am using code blocks and I know how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<int > ::iterator it;
```

Is a global variable. Each time the ham function is called recursively it is used and overwritten so when ham returns the iterator is in a wrong state. Move the iterator inside the ham function so each time ham is called it has its own iterator.